# How to hide Infowindow when using Arcgis Measurement widget?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using [infotemplates](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html#infotemplates) in [ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html) to show the info popups on the map.

But the problem arises when using Measurement tool the infowindow popups on every click on the map. Since I haven't placed any listeners or code for fetching the features and showing the info window. I don't know how to stop this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only stop the info window from coming up. The query will still go to the server to fetch the features.

I did this by using IdentifyTask and then setting InfoTemplate based on the layer on getting the result from the IdentifyTask.

Answer (score 1):

on map object you can call setInfoWindowOnClick(false);

Comment: chiru is right.  you can call map.setInfoWindowOnClick(false) in the console of [this](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/map_twodynamic/) sample application to see a demonstration.